# Simulator for Openflow in LTE

Tags: ns-3, mininet, openflow, sdn, lte

I am currently researching on SDN in mobile networks (LTE). for that i am looking for a simulator, need advise.

I have gone through NS3 and it appears as it supports Openflow Switches, but couldn't find documentation for that purpose. Need help in simulating SDN network in LTE. any suggestion/advise would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Shahzoob

Comment: Have you looked at the NS-3 manual? https://www.nsnam.org/docs/models/html/openflow-switch.html

Answer (score -1):

NS-3 has a module called ofsoftswitch13 which might be quite helpful in your case. It implements controller entity as well as OF 13 protocol.

Answer (score -1):

I did an undergraduate thesis on this topic and used Mininet and Ns-3 together using [this project](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/wiki/Link-modeling-using-ns-3). We primarily did validity testing on this platform to determine it's accuracy and limitations (especially at scale). The wireless model is very good until a very clear performance degradation when the CPU usage reaches (100/n)% - where n is the number of available cores on the machine (for a single threaded implementation).